# How does Wordpress convert a wp_post record into a page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting to work on an existent Wordpress project and I have spent a few hours reading documentations. I have a very specific question. As far as I know, all pages are stored as wp_posts records. This is the schema

[image]

yet, when I browser the pages via Wordpress Admin, I am puzzled. I see the content of some pages and some HTML there, but what puzzles me I have viewed the details of a page and have seen its content is empty, however, the page has dynamic content. I would like to redesign some pages, but I do not see where the PHP code related to them is written.

My question is simple, but I do not find anything after a lot of searching:

Which wordpress files are converting wp_posts into pages which are displayed in the browser and how is the code generated?

Comment: Download and install Wordpress. The code is all in PHP so you can read it and find out for yourself

Comment: I'm not clear on the exact issue you're facing. Are you saying a WP page is being displayed in your browser but in the WP admin you can't find the content of that page?

Comment: And Sorry, but with a rep lke yours you should also know that this question is way Off Topic and Too Broad

Comment: Basically, those PHP files are templates which load content from a database, usually using the "wordpress loop" More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Comment: @j08691 I would like to work on the pages by writing code. I find it difficult to locate where the codes are. Basically an algorithm which describes the way relevant code for a page is to be found would answer the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not offended at all, but a question about how Wordpress transforms a wp_posts entry into a page is a programming question and I think it is not broad at all. I am also convinced that my question is helpful for other people being in my situation later, who have to work on a Wordpress project and do not find a tutorial which explains how to find the page's code. For instance I have viewed the post_content of several pages and in some cases it was empty, yet I see content of the page. So the source is somewhere else. Not among the files, not in post_content, but where?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not asking about the exact place of my content, but rather about a way to gather such information about Wordpress. Brasofilo, for instance, gave a meaningful answer, but some links are still missing between the knowledge presented here and being able to determine where the code is.

Comment: Nobody ever does when its their question. However 4 other people at least agreed with me so I am afraid the question has been put on hold

Comment: @RiggsFolly those are the rules indeed, but I would like to remind you that I would not consider this question to be broad even if it was asked by someone else. I genuinely think that asking for such an algorithm is not a broad question, as I am sure there are some clear steps which, if followed would yield the precise result I have defined. So I do not really understand why did you implied a presumed subjectivity from my part, but anyway, no hard feelings from my part. I will find out the answer myself then.

Comment: "Which wordpress files are converting wp_posts" There are no such files, I would say. You usually have a basic query, ie. WP_Query, that gets the content of a required post type, and you have themes that display that content using different template tags. For anything else, you need to refer to the core files, as mentioned in the previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

The main information that `wp_posts` stores is basically the post ID (post can have various types, post proper, pages, custom post types like products or portfolio items), the title and the content.

Apart from taxonomies and comments, everything else goes on `wp_postmeta`, if your research for a given post ID in this table you'll find most of the dynamic content created by WP (thumbnail, page template, attached files, attachments metadata, etc) and by themes and plugins.

Some plugins will create custom tables, like WooCommerce that creates a dozen+ of tables prefixed with `woocommerce_`.

The basic functions that deal with the meta content are [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and [`set_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_meta/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing I do not really know is how an existing page is converted into a page to be served to the browser. I would like to modify the pages writing HTML, PHP, CSS, MySQL and Javascript code, but I am really struggling to find the place to be implemented. This is why I am asking the question of how a wp_posts record is converted into a page at runtime. If I knew how it works, I would be able to work with it. Unfortunately the tutorials I watched were not clearly answering my specific question.

Comment: @LajosArpad A theme's template files play a big part of this. Themes can have a handful of files, which serve all the content using a bare minimum amount of PHP/HTML/CSS, or they can have dozens of files, to the point where individual template files, e.g. special-page.php, apply to just one page .

Comment: @Lajos, as j08691 points out I just answered the DB part of the thing, you need to dig into this: https://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: @brasofilo thank you, I will.